# How to iterate through stor proc parameters and write each output in separate dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to use same stored procedure with different parameters.

So I want to iterate through parameters and write outcome of the stored procedure in separate dataframes. (List of dataframes). Then I should be able to call each dataframe using index `df[0]` or `df[1]`

From what I understand `df_rpt` is a list of dataframes, where I should be able to call any of those by specifying index.

Am I wrong?

Python code:

```
params = [par1, par2]

# iterate thru each parameter
for par in params:
    query = f""" SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC {stor_proc} {par} """ 
    cursor = connection_string.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.nextset() # first returned table from stor proc is irrelevant - so skip it, move on to second one
    column_names = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    df = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        df.append({name: row[i] for i, name in enumerate(column_names)})
        df_rpt = pd.DataFrame(df)
    print(df_rpt[0])
```

**Error message:**

```
   File "C:\Users\Username
 Files\Python\venvname\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
        indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
      File "C:\Users\username
Files\Python\venvname\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    KeyError: 0
```

Comment: `df_rpt` is a single DataFrame because you do `df_rpt = pd.DataFrame(df)`

Comment: Thanks. Then at what point should I make it as a list of dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is appending several dataframes to `df` as a list, but then trying to access the first (0) of those dataframes in `df_rpt`, which is not a list but a dataframe, as pointed out by @not_speshal.

I suggest that you try replacing this portion of code:

```py
for par in params:
    ...
    df = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        df.append({name: row[i] for i, name in enumerate(column_names)})
        df_rpt = pd.DataFrame(df)
    print(df_rpt[0])
```

with this one:

```py
for par in params:
    ...
    df_rpt = [
        pd.DataFrame({name: row[i] for i, name in enumerate(column_names)})
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
    print(df_rpt[0])
```